# Error Rate from a classifier on random data

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, classification

How is result (C) calculated? Could someone describe the rationale using simple words?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to this site! Please consider adding the [tag:self-study] tag and check its description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a dataset of 100 people, some of them have a disease (positive) and some don't (negative).

If two-thirds belong to the positive class then 66.6 people have the disease, while the remaining 33.3 people in the negative class don't have the disease.

If a (very bad) test for the disease is made that always says that the person does have the disease (positive) then it's going to be correct for those 66.6 people that actually have the disease. Meanwhile the 33.3 people that don't have the disease still get a positive result, which is a mistake.

Here 33.3 out of 100 people get the wrong result from the test. The error rate (errors / all people * 100) is then 33.3/100*100 = 33.3%. The text seems to have rounded this to 33%.

Comment: The training and testing set should really follow the same patterns. Since the classifier isn't really 'trained' on the training set the testing result should be the same as training.